# Adding '+' to the end of Algolia instantsearch rangeslider's max value

Tags: javascript, algolia

I'm using Algolia's rangeslider from instantsearch.js with tooltips set to false.  When the slider's maximum value is displayed (the value to the right side of the slider) (e.g: 2,000), I want it to display as (e.g: 2,000+) (with a "+").

I've tried accessing/resetting the value with jquery like this:

```
var $sliderMax = $('#my_slider_identifier .ais-range-slider--value').last();
```

And I've succeeded in getting a handle on the variable, but when I try resetting the maximum value from a custom widget's render() function (so it updates with each new set of results coming in) with the equivalent of `$sliderMax.text('2,000' + '+')`, nothing happens - I assume because the DOM is being re-written after my call..

If the rangeSlider is showing the maximum value (e.g: 2000), Is there a recommended way to put a '+' on the end?

**EDIT:**
To give more background: Though I have a range of values from 0-10,000+, the vast majority of the data is in the 0-2000 range, and I thus, truncated my data so that if it's >2000, it shows as 2000.

Also, incidentally and oddly, As a hack, I found that I can write to the DOM if I use a setTimeout of 0 ms (yes, [there are stackoverflows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful) on this) and re-do a JQuery selection:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#index_price_eur_day_i .ais-range-slider--value').last()
        .text(MAX_PRICE_SLIDER + '+');}, 0);
```

I'd love to find a more-efficient solution.

Comment: One small question: if this is the maximum value, why do you want to put a `+` after it since there are none above?

Comment: @Jerska Before I'm dealing with e.g: $/day and I want my slider go from 0 to $2000+.  I have some entries that go as high as 10,000, but I intentionally set that facet value to max at 2000 (in that case) - because I want a smaller spread for my slider. Hope this answers the question!

Comment: I'm not sure I'll be able to answer the question, but you did definitely answer mine!

Answer (score 3):

I heard from Tim Carry of Algolia and he suggested that I try the `:after` pseudo element of CSS to fix this.

Indeed, I added this CSS and it always adds a + -- unfortunately even when the slider is not at the max value :/

```
#my_slider_identifier .ais-range-slider--value:last-of-type::after { 
    content: "+";
}
```

So it's not a perfect solution, but it may be "good-enough" - and it's not as ugly/inefficient as using jquery. If anyone has a better solution, please post it!